# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'id' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have an errors

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/jsp/players/playersList.jsp at line 39
36:         </thead>
37:         <c:forEach items="${model.playersList}}" var="player" >
38:         <tbody>
39:             <td><c:out value="${player.id}" /> </td>
40:             <td><c:out value="${player.firstName}"/> </td>
41:             <td>$(player.lastName)</td>
42:             <td>$(player.tournamentsIdPlusNameHistory)</td>
```

and

`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'id' not found on type java.lang.String`

The model is:

```
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String city;
private Array tournamentsIdPlusNameHistory;
private Date lastActivity;
private int rating;
private String rank;
private String email;
```

with getters and setters like this:

```
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id =  id;
}
```

This is a controller

```
public ModelAndView getPlayers(Map<String, Object> model) {
    List<Player> playersList = playerDao.getAll();
    model.put("players", playersList);
    return new ModelAndView("players/playersList", model);
}
```

This is .jsp file:

```
<c:forEach items="${model.playersList}}" var="player" >
    <tbody>
        <td><c:out value="${player.id}" /> </td>
        <td><c:out value="${player.firstName}"/> </td>
        <td>$(player.lastName)</td>
        <td>$(player.tournamentsIdPlusNameHistory)</td>
        <td>$(player.lastActivity)</td>
        <td>$(player.rating)</td>
        <td>$(player.rank)</td>
        <td>$(player.email)</td>
    </tbody>
</c:forEach>
```

I really don't understant what is the problem because I found a lot of problems like that and tried to follow all advices but it still does not work.

Comment: This project exist on github also https://github.com/SolidaSlOl/belarusGo

Comment: Your `items` expression is wrong. It contains a `}` to much. and your model object is named `players` not `playersList`. Rewrite your items expression to the correct thing. `<c:forEach items="${players}" var="player" >`

Comment: It works now. I mean there is no errors but values are not showing but it is another story ;D Thanks

Comment: Turned out model. is not needed

Comment: adding to M.deinum's comment,
@MikitaHerasiutsin  got the same issue as yours,but mistake from my side was different,i ddn't provided the items expression (as ${list}) for listing

Answer (score 3):

You have set the model attribute as `players` which contains `List<Players>`. In the for loop you have to make changes like this,

```
<c:forEach items="${players}" var="player" >
<tbody>
    <td><c:out value="${player.id}" /> </td>
    <td><c:out value="${player.firstName}"/> </td>
    <td>${player.lastName}</td>
    <td>${player.tournamentsIdPlusNameHistory}</td>
    <td>${player.lastActivity}</td>
    <td>${player.rating}</td>
    <td>${player.rank}</td>
    <td>${player.email}</td>
</tbody>
</c:forEach>
```

While printing you have also used round brackets `()` instead of curly brackets `{}`.

Comment: @Mikita Herasiutsin, if this answer helped you or solved your problem, then please mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a entity class like

```
@Entity
class User{
@Id
int id
String name;
String password;
public String getName()//This should be getname or getName if it is something else it will cause issue
{

}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not quite sure but
I see the 'id' property is set to private.

Is it possible to access private member variable with ${} expression?

Comment: No that's nothing to do with that, entity fields don't need to be public